# how to load content of a file to third part editor ex:(Wysiwyg editor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using third party WYSIWYG editor in my web application. I want to load the content from a file. How can I load the content? (javascript or React js)

```js
var filecontent; 

function selection(){ 
  var filevalue=document.getElementById('files').value; 
  if(filevalue=="A"){ 
    fetchDetailsA(); 
  } 
}

function fetchDetailsA() {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      filecontent = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById('NicEdit').innerHTML = filecontent;
      document.myForm.NicEdit.value += "Hello";
      alert(document.myForm.NicEdit.value)
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "Textfiles/Sample1.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <textarea id="NicEdit" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get some error? Where is `filecontent` declared?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: So what's your issue? Does your code load the file? Is this function called somewhere?

Comment: var filecontent;
        
            function selection(){
                
                var filevalue=document.getElementById('files').value;
                
                if(filevalue=="A"){
                
                    fetchDetailsA();
                }
                 
            }

Comment: issue is i have list of files in dropdown by selecting among one of them i have to load the content of file into a textarea of third party wysiwyg editor and my function is returning the content but not loading into the textare of that editor and i am calling function in dropdown by event onchange....

Comment: My HTML Code:<form name="myForm">
                <select id="files" onchange="selection()">
                    <option>Select File</option>
                    <option>A</option>
                    <option>B</option>
                    <option>C</option>
                </select>
                
               
                <p id="demo"></p>
                
                <textarea id="NicEdit" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" onclick="send()"/>
            </form>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetch api introduces in javascript to make this much easier.

```
fetch('Textfiles/Sample1.json')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
      document.getElementById('NicEdit').innerHTML = text;
      document.myForm.NicEdit.value += "Hello";
  })
```

Comment: i am getting the response from api but not loading the content of api to text area